# Nested transactions with OrientGraph

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to use nested transactions with OrientGraph , but it does not seem to work properly 
my scenario is

```
function1(){
    OrientGraph db = factory.openDatabase() ; // which will give active graph on current thread
    db.begin();

    function2();

    // save some data 
    db.commit();
}

function2(){

    OrientGraph db = factory.openDatabase() ; // which will give active graph on current thread
    db.begin();

    // save some data 

    db.commit(); // this commit is saving the data into db 

}
```

commit in function2 saves data , but its part of nested transaction it should be commited at the moment when commit happens on outer transaction

am i doing something wrong ?

Note : i am doing db.setAutoStartTx(false); so that it will not start transaction automatically

Answer (score 2):

You should use the same database instance object.
To automate this process (and get performance speed up) I suggest you use com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool class. Also I always suggest you to use this pool because it minimizes time is need to acquire new collection and scales very well on multicore H/ w.

Comment: yes , i am using OrientGraphFactory ( which internally creates OPartitionedDatabasePool )  and db instances in both functions are same , but still nested transactions functionality is not working

Comment: sample code is available here,    https://gist.github.com/anonymous/54cd70a1e53d0381658a

commit in  function2 commits data created in outer transaction (function1).
please let  me know if i am doing something wrong . 
thank you ..!

Comment: it works if i do something like this 
https://gist.github.com/linus46/5019a523f0c32ad146f7

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Try using `db.getRawGraph().activateOnCurrentThread()` after the function 2

```
function1(){
    OrientGraph db = factory.openDatabase() ; // which will give active graph on current thread
    db.begin();

    function2();

    db.getRawGraph().activateOnCurrentThread();

    // save some data 
    db.commit();
}
```

Comment: No , its not working , since there is no db.activateOnCurrentThread(); on OrientGraph , I used db.getRawGraph().activateOnCurrentThread()